# Bootstrap 3 text inside container over full-width image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

So my graphic artist came up with a layout that I am having trouble coming up with a clean solution to. Basically they want a full-width responsive image, with text over it. But the text has to be left-aligned and fit within a `container` div, instead of being full width too. I also need to take care of mobile/tablets/etc. so I have to make sure the font size works on all devices too (hence the font resizing in the JQuery/JS).

So I was just wondering if I am doing this the most efficient way possible.  I feel like bootstrap should have something to fix this issue and that I just missed it, but this is the best solution I could come up with (WARNING: code is still a work in progress, don't hate me for poor JS/JQuery =D)

So here is my BootPly with the solution I came up with:
http://www.bootply.com/bdS9H3otpi

I am hoping someone will be like, oh boy that was overkill just do X, but for the life of me I cannot think of what X will be.

P.S. My question was basically answered by myself, I am just hoping there is a cleaner solution. If no one can come up with one I will just clean up the JQuery/Javascript code and use it as is

Comment: first of all the JS not working in firefox and what JS is doing you can achieve via CSS ... I am working on the fiddle now will post answer ... btw the design dont worth all this effort ... in mobile and tablet the image not showing at all its better if replace it with bg color .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all no need for JS .

1- main part put the image  as back ground and the text as title ( h1 )

2- for responsive use only CSS

for example

```
#newsHeaderTitle{
  color:white;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  font-size:350%;
   line-height:350%;
}
/* image BG image */

@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
    #newsHeaderTitle{font-size:350%;line-height:300%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    #newsHeaderTitle{font-size:300%;line-height:350%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    #newsHeaderTitle{font-size:200%;line-height:350%;}
    /* image BG tablet image */
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    #newsHeaderTitle{font-size:100%;line-height:100%;}
    /* image BG mobile image */
}
```

try to use all height and sizes in EM its better than % 
dont add your CSS in html .

Comment: So I would just add different sized header images for different screen sizes? What about when they are between screen sizes (ie: resizing the browser window on a desktop)?

Comment: the reason we do responsive images is to load less data on mobile and tablet ... about desktop you will have 3 images 
1- for 1920
2- for 1320
3- for 1000
I recommend make them even 1 
so you will have total 
one big image , one tablet , one mobile .

Comment: Sounds good to me. I knew I was overthinking this! Thanks J. Tural